# Getting an error when checking if values in a list match a column PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just wondering how one might overcome the below error.

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'**

What I am trying to do is create a new column "PrivilegedAccess" and in this column I want to write "True" if any of the names in the first_names column match the ones outlined in the "Search_for_These_values" list and "False" if they don't

Code

```
## Create list of Privileged accounts
Search_for_These_values = ['Privileged','Diagnostics','SYS','service account'] #creating list

pattern = '|'.join(Search_for_These_values)     # joining list for comparision

PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns=[['first_name']].str.contains(pattern)
PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'].map({True: 'True', False: 'False'})
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
    uid last_name   first_name  language    role    email_address   department
0   121 Chad    Diagnostics English Team Lead   Michael.chad@gmail.com  Data Scientist
1   253 Montegu Paulo   Spanish CIO Paulo.Montegu@gmail.com Marketing
2   545 Mitchel Susan   English Team Lead   Susan.Mitchel@gmail.com Data Scientist
3   555 Vuvko   Matia   Polish  Marketing Lead  Matia.Vuvko@gmail.com   Marketing
4   568 Sisk    Ivan    English Supply Chain Lead   Ivan.Sisk@gmail.com Supply Chain
5   475 Andrea  Patrice Spanish Sales Graduate  Patrice.Andrea@gmail.com    Sales
6   365 Akkinapalli Cherifa French  Supply Chain Assistance Cherifa.Akkinapalli@gmail.com   Supply Chain
```

Note that the dtype of the first_name column is "object" and the dataframe is multi index (not sure how to change from multi index)

Many thanks

Comment: Is this syntax expected `PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns=[['first_name']].str.contains(pattern)` @sqlworrier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need select one column for `str.contains` and then use map or convert boolean to strings:

```
Search_for_These_values = ['Privileged','Diagnostics','SYS','service account'] #creating list
pattern = '|'.join(Search_for_These_values)

PrivilegedAccounts_DF = pd.DataFrame({'first_name':['Privileged 111',
                                                    'aaa SYS',
                                                    'sss']})

print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns)
Index(['first_name'], dtype='object')

print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[0, 'first_name'])
Privileged 111

print (type(PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[0, 'first_name']))
<class 'str'>
```

---

```
PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].str.contains(pattern).astype(str)
print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF)
       first_name PrivilegedAccess
0  Privileged 111             True
1         aaa SYS             True
2             sss            False
```

EDIT:

There is problem one level MultiIndex, need:

```
PrivilegedAccounts_DF = pd.DataFrame({'first_name':['Privileged 111',
                                                    'aaa SYS',
                                                    'sss']})

#simulate problem
PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns = [PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns.tolist()]
print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF)
       first_name
0  Privileged 111
1         aaa SYS
2             sss

#check columns
print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns)
MultiIndex([('first_name',)],
           )
```

Solution is join values, e.g. by empty string:

```
PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns = PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns.map(''.join)
```

So now columns names are correct:

```
print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns)
Index(['first_name'], dtype='object')

PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].str.contains(pattern).astype(str)
print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF)
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thanks for the comment. If I use the code you have above (including removing the double brakets for first_name) I still get the error **TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index**

Comment: @sqlworrier - No idea, for me working perfectly. Are in column `PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name']` only strings?

Comment: No the dtype of PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'] is "object"

Comment: @sqlworrier - yes, it means strings.

Comment: @jezrael I think there is some syntax related issues with OP's code.

Comment: Would it have something to do with the dataframe being multi index?

Comment: @Vishnudev - yes, possible, because error never seen before.

Comment: The attribute error is because of this code `[['first_name']].str.contains`

Comment: Even when I remove the double brackets I get the same error

Comment: @sqlworrier - added some `print` before `PrivilegedAccounts_DF['PrivilegedAccess'] = PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].str.contains(pattern).astype(str)` can you test if same ouputs in real data?

Comment: @jezrael I can't print that as the function isn't executing. However when i print the following i get print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[0, 'first_name']) first_name    Raul
                                                                              Name: 0, dtype: object

Comment: Also print (type(PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[0, 'first_name'])) is saying I have a series "<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"

Comment: @sqlworrier - What is `print (type(PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name']))` ?

Comment: @jezrael **print (type(PrivilegedAccounts_DF[['first_name']]))** returns **<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>**                                                                                                               However if I run **print (type(PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name']))** like you mentioned I get an error (I need the 2 brackets) - error: **TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index**

Comment: @sqlworrier So if use `print(PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].tolist())` working?

Comment: @jezrael that does not work unfortunately. It returns the same error

Comment: @sqlworrier - Is possible reinstall pandas?

Comment: @jezrael I only got anaconda installed recently do you think this is the issue? I did do lots of manipulation on the dataframe too before trying the query it so not sure if this might be the issue

Comment: @sqlworrier - Hmm, are data confidental?

Comment: @jezrael data is confidential but I can share some dummy data and the code if you would like

Comment: @sqlworrier - Ya, only test if same errro in dummy data. If not, not sense share.

Comment: I think the error is because the DF I have is ** <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> ** . I have loaded dummy data without the manipulation and the DF is **<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>** The code works when I have a series but not a DafaFrame

Comment: @sqlworrier - yes, if use `PrivilegedAccounts_DF[['first_name']]` get DataFrame. But if use `PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name']` get `Series` BUT if there are 2 or more columns `first_name` got `DataFrame`

Comment: @jezrael  Not sure if I understand. I have even tried to convert the DF to a series by using PrivilegedAccounts_DF.squeeze() but even when I do this the function still won't work (same error)

Comment: @sqlworrier - Waht is `print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF[['first_name']].head().to_numpy().tolist())`

Comment: @jezrael that returns the following **[['Raul'], ['Chad'], ['Bryan'], ['Miguel'], ['Shailaja']]** which are the first 5 names in my actual dataset

Comment: @jezrael - Can you explain what this is doing please?, I know I am converting the data to a list but I am still getting an error when I execute the code that returns True or False when searching for the strings

Comment: @sqlworrier - no idea, it seems some data problem or pandas problem. In my answer workign nice, hard to know what is problem.

Comment: looks like the error is because the dataframe isn't a series. Not sure how to overcome it

Comment: @sqlworrier - What is `print (PrivilegedAccounts_DF.columns)` ?

Comment: @Jezrael - its a multi index -  **MultiIndex([(          'uid',),
            (    'last_name',),
            (   'first_name',),
            ('accessibility',),
            (         'role',)],
           )**

Comment: @sqlworrier - How was created DataFrame `PrivilegedAccounts_DF`?

Comment: @sqlworrier - exactly there is ptoblem, MultiIndex

Comment: really? :O please do share, I have been trying to ovecome this issue for the past few days now and I've went through so many lines of code

Comment: so this was the format of the data **[User]
Field=Data
employeeNo=123
last_name=Toole
first_name=Michael
language=english
email = michael.toole@123.ie
department=Marketing
role=Marketing Lead
[User]
employeeNo=456
last_name= Ronaldo
first_name=Juan
language=Spanish
email=juan.ronaldo@sms.ie
department=Data Science
role=Team Lead
Location=Spain
[User]
employeeNo=998
last_name=Lee
first_name=Damian
language=english
email=damian.lee@email.com
[User]**

Comment: @jezrael - Wow, thank you so so much for this, it is hugely appreciated

Comment: @jezrael - Super helpful! answer is accepted thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this should work (without using `patterns`):

```
PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].isin(Search_for_These_values), "PrivilegedAccess"]=True
PrivilegedAccounts_DF.loc[~PrivilegedAccounts_DF['first_name'].isin(Search_for_These_values), "PrivilegedAccess"]=False
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I am still getting an error **TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index** think it's because my dataframe is not a series